# Get nodes from xml string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have string xml like below:

```
<Query>
  <Code>USD</Code>
  <Description>United States Dollars</Description>
  <UpdateTime>2013-03-04 02:27:33</UpdateTime>
  <toUSD>1</toUSD>
  <USDto>1</USDto>
  <toEUR>2</toEUR>
  <EURto>3</EURto>
</Query>
```

All text is in one line without white spaces. I can't write right regex pattern. I want get nodes which begin like `<to`. For example `<toEUR>`, `<toUSD>`.

How should I write this pattern?

Comment: [Please don't use RegEx for XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Which language? It would be better to use an actual XML library (or xpath, or anything but regex).

Comment: In Ruby. For me that is a short plain text, so I decide to use regex.

Comment: @user1931951: A few options: http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-xml.html

Comment: Even for simple(-looking) regex/XML IMO it's almost never worth it since there are many options available.

Answer (score 0):

With nokogiri and the xpath function `starts-with`:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML <<EOF
<Query>
  <Code>USD</Code>
  <Description>United States Dollars</Description>
  <UpdateTime>2013-03-04 02:27:33</UpdateTime>
  <toUSD>1</toUSD>
  <USDto>1</USDto>
  <toEUR>2</toEUR>
  <EURto>3</EURto>
</Query>
EOF

doc.search('//*[starts-with(name(),"to")]').map &:to_s
#=> ["<toUSD>1</toUSD>", "<toEUR>2</toEUR>"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Although the general consensus is that parsing xml etc with regex is not the way to go, something like this should do the trick:

```
<\s*(to[^>\s]+)[^>]*>([^<]+)<\s*/\s*\1\s*>
```

In ruby format:

```
/<\s*(to[^>\s]+)[^>]*>([^<]+)<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>/
```

Matches `<toWatever>value</toWhatever>` back-reference group 1 returns the name (toWhatever) and back-reference group 2 returns the value.